# User Friendly, Easy to Remember Coupon Codes

Tags: php, security, language-agnostic

I want to create coupon codes that users can remember easily.  My idea is something like:

- squirrel45
- nantucket23

That is, a real word chosen randomly from a long dictionary list (preferably compiled for this purpose) combined 2 random digits.  My questions are:

1. Where can I find such a dictionary list?
2. Do you see any problems with the system?  (security is not ultra important here, just something reasonable is fine)
3. Can you suggest any good improvements or alternatives?

Fwiw I am not crazy about the Markov word generators because I think their idiosyncrasies would be too hard to remember.  I'd like a client to be able to keep the code in his head, and tell it to the merchant when he arrives to redeem it.

Thanks,
Jonah

Comment: Some questions which would help: How many codes will be provisioned? Do they need to be unique? Can they be reused? Is it important that they're not easily discoverable? What is the impact if they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word lists are easy to find. Make sure you sanity filter them for foul words ;)

Here's a huge word list that can be easily scrubbed:

http://www.scrabble-assoc.com/boards/dictionary/10-15-20030401.txt

From there you can easily load in words into your database and create your coupon code like so:

```
$coupon_code = $rand_word . rand(20,99);
```

After you do this, simply store your coupon code in the database and whenever you make a new code, check it against existing codes before you apply it. Even slim odds are possible odds.

More word lists in various formats:

http://scrabble.wonderhowto.com/blog/ultimate-scrabble-word-list-resource-0115617/

5-letter words: 
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/adam.bozon/Scrabble5.htm

6-letter words: 
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/adam.bozon/Scrabble6.htm

7-letter words: 
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/adam.bozon/Scrabble7.htm

8-letter words: 
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/adam.bozon/Scrabble8.htm

Sample:

> PIKES PIKIS PILAF PILAR PILAU PILAW PILEA PILED PILEI PILES PILIS
>   PILLS PILOT PILUS PIMAS PIMPS PINAS PINCH PINED PINES PINEY PINGO
>   PINGS PINKO PINKS PINKY PINNA PINNY PINON PINOT PINTA PINTO PINTS
>   PINUP PIONS PIOUS PIPAL PIPED PIPER PIPES PIPET PIPIT PIQUE PIRNS
>   PIROG PISCO PISOS PISTE PITAS PITCH PITHS PITHY PITON PIVOT PIXEL
>   PIXES PIXIE PIZZA PLACE PLACK PLAGE PLAID PLAIN PLAIT PLANE PLANK
>   PLANS PLANT PLASH PLASM PLATE PLATS PLATY PLAYA PLAYS PLAZA PLEAD
>   PLEAS PLEAT PLEBE PLEBS PLENA PLEWS PLICA PLIED PLIER PLIES PLINK
>   PLODS PLONK PLOPS PLOTS PLOTZ PLOWS PLOYS PLUCK PLUGS PLUMB PLUME
>   PLUMP PLUMS PLUMY PLUNK PLUSH PLYER POACH POCKS POCKY PODGY PODIA
>   POEMS POESY POETS POGEY POILU POIND POINT POISE POKED POKER POKES

With that you could generate a coupon code `POACH72`

Comment: It would be nice to use a word list that avoids obscure words, especially ones that might easily be mistaken for other words. I think OP's problem is a little trickier to solve well than this answer.

Comment: I thought it was obvious but....this wordlist was just an example to show how the lists are formatted usually and how they could be parsed out. OP can use whatever wordlist he wants, and I'm sure there is a list with commonly used words readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating 2 words will increase the security posture of your system.
e.g. squirrel.nantucket.123

Answer (score 1):

The [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) page has a couple of long word lists, American and International.  It also has a useful description of how to meet various levels of security.